# What to write here: Rock or Rocked or Have Rocked

Tags: tense

I have come across this headline on newspaper "Clashes rock downtown." 
Since it's a finished action a day before. How come the editor has used present tense. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Newspaper headlines are often written in the present tense, even when the events they describe are completed. This is known as the 'vivid' or 'historical' present. It is a feature of many languages, not only English. The idea is that the use of a present tense creates immediacy and drama. You will also find it in fiction and literature.

Comment: Also note that headlines often omit little words such as articles, and _is_. In this case the headline is a valid sentence in normal English, but often they are not.

Comment: Yes, a lot of headlines are written this way. If I'm not mistaken, whether they use the present tense or past tense depends on whether they use the passive or active voice. For example, "Woman kills husband" and "Man killed by wife" are both valid ways to report a murder.

Answer (score 0):

**Clashes rock downtown**  (e.g. Since the last edition of our paper there have been clashes)

**Last week clashes rocked downtown. Police arrest the rioters** (You probably know about the clashes. This is an update)

**Clashes have rocked downtown nearly every month this year** (Here are the statistics gathered over a period of time)